# Selectively pushing files that have already been added and committed

Tags: git

Here is what I have done:

1. cloned a git repository.
2. Made some changes to the files.
3. Created a new branch, checked out the branch.
4. Added the files, committed the changes and then pushed the changes.

Now, while pushing I realized that there were too many files because some were video files which I did not want to push. So I press Ctrl+C to cancel the push.

I realized that there was no .gitignore file, so I am stuck here.

```
$ git status
# On branch new-branch
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

So, now I want to push all the files except the .mp4 video files (which are in many subfolders) which are also already added and committed in git.

What should I do?

Comment: Where the video files pushed to the remote or not?

Comment: No they were not puhsed, as I cancelled it before it reached 100%.

Answer (score 4):

You should first remove the videos from index:

```
git rm --cached path/to/videos/*.mp4
```

This leaves the files alone, it only removes them from git - as if they have never been added to the index.

Now you should add a `.gitignore` file and add the path(s) to the videos there and then add it to git:

```
git add .gitignore
```

Now you can `commit --amend` which will modify the recent commit:

```
git commit --amend
```

Finally push:

```
git push origin branchname
```

---

Btw, you could use almost the same commands if you had already pushed to the remote, except that you would need to add the `-f` (`--force`) option to `git push`. But you need to get sure that nobody else already pulled from the remote since otherwise you would mess things up.

Answer (score 2):

Bulk index operations can be easiest with `git update-index`, like so:

```
git ls-files \*.mp4 | git update-index --force-remove --stdin
```

Amend your commit:

```
git commit --no-edit --amend
```

Push it

```
git push --force origin    # the server might not allow this
```

and you're good. git will eventually clean out the garbage, just forget about it and let it do its job.

Answer (score 1):

This is your scenario. You have mistakenly added, committed, *and pushed* a bunch of `mp4` files. I recreated a similar scenario:

```
> git add -A
> git status

new file:   a.mp4
new file:   b.mp4
new file:   c.mp4
new file:   d.mp4
new file:   e.mp4
new file:   good-file.txt
new file:   good-file1.txt
new file:   good-file2.txt
new file:   subdir/f.mp4
new file:   subdir/subdir/g.mp4

> git commit -m "Add new files."

> git push
```

The `mp4` files are now polluting the remote repository.

Note that you also pushed a few `txt` files that you want to keep in the remote. To remove the `mp4` files, first update your .gitignore by adding the following line (this assumes that you want to ignore *all* mp4 files - otherwise you would have to add more specific paths.)

```
*.mp4
```

Then run the following git commands. First, recursively remove all `mp4` files from your index. Then, amend your last commit; since the `mp4` files are no longer in the index, they will not be in the amended commit.  Finally, force push your new, rewritten commit to the remote upstream.

```
> git rm --cached -r *.mp4

rm 'a.mp4'
rm 'a1.mp4'
rm 'a2.mp4'
rm 'bar.mp4'
rm 'foo.mp4'
rm 'subdir/foobar.mp4'
rm 'subdir/subdir/foofoo.mp4'

> git commit --amend -m "Add new files without mp4s"
> git push -f
```

Result: the remote no longer has your `mp4` files. **Warning**: if other developers have already pulled your first commit, they will have to rebase off of your rewritten one.